# Finding almost minimum cycle

Tags: graph-algorithms

Given an undirected unweighted graph, the almost minimum cycle is defined as the cycle whose length is greater than that of a minimum cycle by at most one. Itai and Rodeh in a seminal paper in 1978 gave a simple O(n^2) algorithm to find such an almost minimum cycle. My question is, has it been improved ever since? If yes, which paper does that?

Comment: For the lazy, here's a [Google-Scholar link](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=9582693746256185614&hl=en&as_sdt=1,22) to the paper.  [Here's](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=9582693746256185614&as_sdt=40000005&sciodt=1,22&hl=en) a link to the papers that cite that one.  As of August 2018, Google Scholar returns only [four papers](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=40000005&sciodt=1%2C22&cites=9582693746256185614&scipsc=1&q=%22almost+minimum%22&oq=) that cite that one and contain the phrase "Almost minimum".